# Dplyr Summarise Groups as Column Names

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I got a data frame with a lot of columns and want to summarise them with multiple functions.

```
test_df <- data.frame(Group = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 10, T), var1 = sample(1:5, 10, T), var2 = sample(3:7, 10, T))

test_df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise_all(c(Mean = mean, Sum = sum))

    # A tibble: 3 x 5
  Group var1_Mean var2_Mean var1_Sum var2_Sum
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <int>    <int>
1 A          3.14      5.14       22       36
2 B          4.5       4.5         9        9
3 C          4         6           4        6
```

This results in a tibble with the first row Group and column names with a combination of the previous column name and the function name.
The desired result is a table with the previous column names as first row and the groups and functions in the column names.

I can achive this with

```
test_longer <- test_df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("var"), names_to = "var", values_to = "val")

# Add row number because spread needs unique identifiers for rows
test_longer <- test_longer %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(grouped_id = row_number())

spread(test_longer, Group, val) %>% 
  select(-grouped_id) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise_all(c(Mean = mean, Sum = sum), na.rm = T)

    # A tibble: 2 x 7
  var   A_Mean B_Mean C_Mean A_Sum B_Sum C_Sum
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1 var1    3.14    4.5      4    22     9     4
2 var2    5.14    4.5      6    36     9     6
```

But this seems to be a rather long detour... There probably is a better way, but I could not find it. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots of ways to go about it, but I would simplify it by pivoting to a longer data frame initially, and then grouping by `var` and `group`. Then you can just pivot wider to get the final result you want. Note that I used `summarize(across())` which replaces the deprecated `summarize_all()`, even though with a single column could've just manually specified `Mean = ...` and `Sum = ...`.

```r
set.seed(123)

test_df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    var1:var2,
    names_to = "var"
  ) %>%
  group_by(Group, var) %>%
  summarize(
    across(
      everything(),
      list(Mean = mean, Sum = sum),
      .names = "{.fn}"
    ),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "Group",
    values_from = c(Mean, Sum),
    names_glue = "{Group}_{.value}"
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>   var   A_Mean B_Mean C_Mean A_Sum B_Sum C_Sum
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 var1       1    2.5    3.2     1    10    16
#> 2 var2       5    4.5    4.4     5    18    22
```